# "Cannot GET" error in REST API using Vue.js

Tags: php, rest, api, vue.js, vue-router

I've got a project made with Vue.js, I run the localhost through npm (Node).

I'm newbie in Rest API's. I've made a simple REST API following an internet tutorial.

employees.php

```
<?php
// Connect to database
    include("../connection.php");
    $db = new dbObj();
    $connection =  $db->getConnstring();

    $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    switch($request_method)
    {
        case 'GET':
            // Retrive Products
            if(!empty($_GET["id"]))
            {
                $id=intval($_GET["id"]);
                get_employees($id);
            }
            else
            {
                get_employees();
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Invalid Request Method
            header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
            break;
    }

    function get_employees()
    {
        global $connection;
        $query="SELECT * FROM employee";
        $response=array();
        $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $response[]=$row;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    function get_employees($id=0)
    {
    global $connection;
    $query="SELECT * FROM employee";
    if($id != 0)
    {
        $query.=" WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
    }
    $response=array();
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $response[]=$row;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    }

 ?>
```

I don't know how to call API's from my Js, etc.
 The problem is how to call my API. I tried via localhost/api/v1/employees.php but i get

> "CANNOT GET employees.php"

error.

I'd like to know the correct way to make a REST API with Vue.js, because i've my DB on XAMPP, and i think there could be the problem. Any link would be valuable to learn more.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Need to see what you have already done on your `js` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "cannot get employees.php" it's possible that your server is telling you that the file is not actually at `localhost/api/v1/employees.php`.

Could you modify your `employees.php` file to read `<?php echo 123; ?>` ?

If you get the same problem, you are likely not using the correct URL structure for your api/server.

Additionally, your server could be blocking the traffic from Javascript, so if you see `123` in your browser, but when you use AJAX it fails, then it could be that you have a [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) issue.

Comment: I've been reading something about CORS but i didn't understand very well. Could it be solverd by code? (CORS problem). Because i've made the same API in another domain, but it only worked with CORS chrome extension. But i can't understand how is it solved in production

Comment: CORS can be different on localhost versus a remote server.  with XXAMP, you may have to enable it at the top of your php file with something like `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` and optionally `header('Content-type: application/json');`